# trying to load a picture into new ViewController from didSelectCellAtIndex

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView and in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method I have instantiating a new ViewController, setting the String property on the ViewController to hold the image's name.  And then in the viewDidLoad OR the viewDidAppear method in the new ViewController I am trying to set the image using the vc.imageName property.

Here is the code:

```
// collection.m


    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

        NSString *imageName = [colouringPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.imageName = imageName;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


// ViewController.h

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * imageName;

//ViewController.m

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *lineImageView;

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.lineImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];
}
```

But the image doesn't show.  I have set the background colour on the ImageView to check that it is being displayed in the new ViewController and I can see it but the image never displays within the UIImageView.

Comment: Yes the name is null when I set a breakpoint in viewDidLoad.  so the name is not being passed to the new ViewController

Comment: if I set a breakpoint at vc.imageName = imageName I can see the imageName is there, but once it is passed to presentViewcontroller it is null in the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Segue to show the next view controller. Assuming you use "ShowNextViewController" as the identifier for your Segue, you could use `prepareForSegue:sender:` to set the `imageName` property of the destination view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(nonnull UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowNextViewController"]) {
        ViewController *destination = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] firstObject];
        destination.imageName = self.colouringPhotos[selectedIndex.row];
    }
}
```

If you have trouble setting up the segue, see [this iOS Developer Library document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) for more information.

Also, see the [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) for more information on the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Comment: That's brilliant - I had just implemented the prepareForSegue method but was missing the selectedIndex line.  Thanks a million.