# Segue to another viewcontroller when clicking on image

Tags: swift

So I have an array of 3 images that show up on my first viewcontroller when I open the app. When I click on the an image(e.g. notes) I want to go to the notes view controller. The same for the other two images.

I've tried connecting the cell to the view controller but whenever I click on any of the images they all bring me to my notes viewcontroller.

```
let locationName = ["Journal", "Calendar", "Emergency Contacts"]

let locationImage = [UIImage(named: "journal.jpg"), UIImage(named: "calendar.jpg"), UIImage(named: "contacts.png")]

let locationDescription = ["A journal to keep track of how you are feeling", "Here you can keep track of all of your appointments", "Store a list of your emergency contacts here"]
```

I feel like there's something I could add here but I don't know what.

Comment: check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370723/trying-to-load-a-picture-into-new-viewcontroller-from-didselectcellatindex

Comment: show us the code where you set the data to the images and its handling !

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return locationName.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I hope thats right. I'm very new to swift.

Comment: in which method do you push to another `viewcontroller` ? attach the code in your question

Comment: I did it in the storyboard. I know that's probably my main mistake.

Comment: Not related, but using 3 array is bad design. Because locationName[0] is linked to locationImage[0] & locationDescription[0]. You should use a custom struct to reflect these logic. And have one single array for them. For the rest, look at didSelectRow method?